# warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning) in MFC(VC++)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am getting this warning "warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)" on below line of code :

```
if (g_objConfigurationDetails.bAutoScan !=  m_objScanNASBtn.GetCheck())
        {
            g_objConfigurationDetails.bAutoScan = m_objScanNASBtn.GetCheck();
}
```

both the lines are giving the same warning.
where bAutoScan  = bool
m_objScanNASBtn = CButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that MFC's [GetCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tba1y6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) doesn't return a bool:

> The return value from a button control created with the BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, BS_AUTO3STATE, BS_CHECKBOX, BS_RADIOBUTTON, or BS_3STATE style is one of the following values:
>   - BST_UNCHECKED - Button state is unchecked.
>   - BST_CHECKED - Button state is checked.
>   - BST_INDETERMINATE - Button state is indeterminate (applies only if the button has the BS_3STATE or BS_AUTO3STATE style).

So you probably want

```
if (g_objConfigurationDetails.bAutoScan
      != (m_objScanNASBtn.GetCheck() == BST_CHECKED))
```

or

```
bool bNASBtnChecked = (m_objScanNASBtn.GetCheck() == BST_CHECKED);
if (g_objConfigurationDetails.bAutoScan != bNASBtnChecked)
{
    g_objConfigurationDetails.bAutoScan = bNASBtnChecked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
g_objConfigurationDetails.bAutoScan = m_objScanNASBtn.GetCheck();
```

should be

```
g_objConfigurationDetails.bAutoScan = m_objScanNASBtn.GetCheck() == BST_CHECKED;
```

The problem is `GetCheck()` doesn't return `bool` so you have to write a comparison - at least in the form of `!= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`GetCheck` returns an integer and you're comparing it to a boolean. Try comparing `GetCheck` to `BST_UNCHECKED` or `BST_CHECKED` depending on your boolean value, or just cast it to boolean since the 2 values match true and false numerically.